# iBooks APIs: What are they using?

Tags: ios, api, swift, uipagecontrol, ibooks

I have a few questions about APIs iBooks uses. For example, is the navigator at the bottom (the blue bar in an iBook) a `UIPageControl` or is it a private API they use? Is the iBooks app built around a `UIPageViewController` to begin with? If the bottom navigator is a `UIPageControl` how can I add that title you see when scrolling your finger along the navigator to show where your finger is in regards to the book?

P.S. If you're kind enough to answer I'd appreciate if you keep to Swift but Obj-C works too. Thanks!

Comment: That's nothing more than a text label placed over a slightly modified UISlider. And I don't know why you are excepting code...

Comment: iBooks API? I don't get it. This is `UIKit` you are asking about. iBook is an app.